# Is there ANY way to retrieve the original input of an sql int field higher than 2147483647?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big table, which saved data with an ID based on input from an external API. The ID is stored in an int field. When I developed the system, I encountered no problems, because the ID of records in the external API were always below 2147483647.

The system has been fetching data from the API for the last few months, and apparantly the ID crossed the 2147483647 mark. I now have a database with thousands of unusable records with ID 2147483647.

It is not possible to fetch this information from the database again (basically, the API allows us to look up data from max x days ago).

I am pretty sure that I am doomed. But might there be any backlog, or any other way, to retrieve the original input queries, or numbers that were truncated by MySQL to fit in the int field?

Comment: why not play around with a bigint column jammed in with `Alter Table`, flip on the 33rd bit, and see if that makes it happy. So copy say idInt32 to idBigInt. Bitwise-Or the 33rd bit to be on.

Comment: Unless you have a log of all queries... no.

Comment: @Drew: huh? The data was truncated... lost... gone.

Comment: you might think it is gone. Have you ever programmed in assembly language with bits?

Comment: @Drew: Yes. Not that it matters here. It's a 32bit field, and was truncated.

Comment: @Drew If the fields are all truncated to 2147483647, what do you think fiddling the bits is going to accomplish?  It would be different if the values wrapped around, but that's not how MySQL works (btw, you really should put it in strict mode so that it throws an error rather than silently truncating)

Comment: right. read the first comment. Alter table adds a new column. He resurrects the values (especially for newer rows). It's not rocket science

Comment: Let me settle this dispute: I have tried Drew's method, and it populates the bigint field with 2147483647. So I am afraid @KarolyHorvath is correct.

Comment: @Drew: You're talking nonsense. But I don't know what to say to persuade you. Please do *try* your fancy "trick" in your sparetime.

Comment: I will give it a shot

Comment: i get an error 1264 out of range error above 2147483647. If you have thousands of rows that are 2147483647, and a datetime column, it can be transposed to (different, other) bigint column with 2147483648 and beyond. Depends on your schema. How that plays fiddle with an external API, or other integrations, above my paygrade

Comment: @Drew Your original idea is very clever, and it might have worked if MySQL did something sensible when it truncates. It doesn't. MySQL does not truncate the out of range value to 32 bits. It simply sets it to 2147483647. There is no information to recover. One could, of course, take each row set to 2147483647 and transpose it to a new column with a new bigint id, but that will have no relationship to the API ID unless it also happens to be incremented linearly.

Comment: I can't speak to the API issue. Just trying to make data usable in some other fashion. Obviously they are wedded, @Schwern

Comment: @Drew These ideas would be better as an answer.

Comment: unless the OP wants another angle at getting at data in some patched hybrid system to make head or tails of transactions, and provides a schema for a few tables, I don't see the point in another answer @Schwern

Comment: MySQL did the right thing (well, an error would be better), it truncated to the biggest value it could store. There is no space in the table to store some extra "overflow value"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, there is no way to retrieve the information from the table.  It was silently(?!!!) truncated to 32 bits.

***First, call the API provider***, explain your situation, and see if you can redo the queries.  Best that happens is they say yes and you don't have to try to reconstruct things from logs.  Worst that happens is they say no and you're back where you are now.

Then there are some logs I would check.

First is the [MySQL General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html).  IF you had this turned on, it may contain the queries which were run.  Another possibility is the [Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html), more often enabled, if your queries happened to be slow.

In MySQL, data truncation is a warning by default.  It's possible those warnings went into a log and included the original data.  The [MySQL Error Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-log.html) is one possibility.  On Windows it may have gone into the [Windows Event Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer).  On a Mac, it might be in a log visible to the [Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28OS_X%29). In Unix, it might have gone to [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).

Then it's possible the API queries themselves are logged somewhere. If you used a proxy it might contain them in its log. The program fetching from the API and adding to the database may also have its own logs. It's a long shot.

As a last resort, try grepping all of `/var/log` and `/var/local/log` and anywhere else you might think could contain a log.

---

In the future there are some things you can do to prevent this sort of thing from happening again.  The most important is to ***turn on [strict SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)***.  This will turn warnings, like that data has been truncated, into errors.

[Set UNIQUE constraints on unique columns](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp).  Had your API ID column been declared UNIQUE the error would have been detected.

Use UNSIGNED BIGINT for numeric IDs.  2 billion is a number easily exceeded these days.  It will mean 4 extra bytes per row or about 8 gigabytes extra to store 2 billion rows.  Disk is cheap.

Consider turning on [ANSI SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi). This will disable a lot of MySQL extensions and make your SQL more portable.

Finally, consider switching to [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). Over the years MySQL has accumulated a lot of bad ideas, mish-mashes of functions, and bad default behaviors. You just got bit by one. PostgreSQL is far better designed, more powerful and flexible, and usually as fast or faster.

In Postgres, you would have gotten an error.

```
test=# CREATE TABLE foo ( id INTEGER );
CREATE TABLE
test=# INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (2147483648);
ERROR:  integer out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have binary logging enabled, and you still have backups of the binlogs, and your `binlog_format` is not set to `ROW` then your original insert and/or update statements should be preserved there, where you could extract them and replay them into another server with a more appropriate table definition.

If you don't have the binlog enabled and/or you aren't archiving the binlogs in perpetuity... this is one of the reasons why you should consider doing it.